# jQuery toggle two different class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usually you can use `.toggleClass()` to switch on/off a specific class eg. `.toggleClass('on')`

But, How can I toggle between two different classes, eg. **left / right**?

My situation: I use a parent `div` and I want to toggle left or right class to change the sidebar position.

```
<div id="page" class="left">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#sidebar {width:25%;}
#container {width:75%;}
#page.right #container,
#page.left #sidebar {float:left;}
#page.left #container,
#page.right #sidebar {float:right;}
```

I hate to use if is left than add right else ...

Comment: `toggle()` controls visibility. `toggleClass()` is the method you want.

Comment: my bad, yes .toggleClass();

Comment: Nice one @David!